# How can I get a new password . Old one not working

Tags: support, status-completed

The one I think is the correct one is not working on a different browser. I am logged on  continually in firefox.

thanks

Comment: You can see the passwords saved in Firefox!  Click right on the page anywhere, then select "Show Page Informations", there click "Security" tab on the top. On the right side, click the "Show saved passwords" button. You get yet another popup, on the bottom right click "Show passwords". The option/button names are not exact, I translate it from a non-English firefox back.

Comment: Here is a doc which shows the more exact clicks: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import?redirectlocale=en-US&as=s&s=saved+password&r=0&esab=a&redirectslug=password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords#w_viewing-and-deleting-passwords Probably you can find also for Greek Firefoxes with a little googling.

Comment: @peterh  tried it, it does not work, still gives me incorrect password or username for the permutation of  guesses I make, cince it does not give me stackexchange. I had logged in with Yahoo or my institute

Comment: If you log in with yahoo, then it shouldn't ask you even a password. It should send you to the yahoo's login page, and after yahoo confirms that you are you, you should be send back to - this time, already logged in - account page.

Comment: @peterh  maybe theoretically. . it does not work. maybe I have a virus/

Comment: I think the cause wasn't a virus, a recent firefox automatic upgrade deleted also some of my passwords.

Answer (score 4):

The "forgot password?" link on the login page will ask you to enter the email address associated with your account. That mails a password reset link to the email address if there's an account associated with it.

I can confirm that you have two email addresses linked with your profile. Same username, one at Yahoo, and one at a .gr domain which is (according to "down for everyone or just me.com") not hosting any web server today.

You can access the login page from your current browser without logging out using a "private browsing" window. In most browsers this option lives in one of the main menus ("file > new") or you can right-click or command-click around the "new tab" button.

If you have trouble getting a password reset link, you'll have to use the contact form that's linked in the footer of every page; the local mods can log you out, but not log you back in.

Comment: thanks the recovery worked on chrome. maybe my trouble came because of the "not hosting a web server". I have no troubke seeing my e-mail at the .gr mail . curiouser and curiouser.